# Highcharts not redrawing when series are updated inside subscribe callback

Tags: typescript, highcharts, angular8, subscribe

I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.service.getSoftwareUsage().subscribe((res) => {
  res.result['data'].forEach(element => {
    this.chartOptions.series.push({ name: element.key, data: [element.value], type: 'column' });//Isn't displayed
  });
  console.log(this.chart);
});
this.chartOptions.series.push({ name: "test", data: [4], type: 'column' }); //Is displayed
}
```

This "works" or at least 90% of it. Every line is executed, and the console.log shows the new series in the chart, however they aren't showing up, i tried to add one manually outside the subscribed call and that one is showing up on the chart.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Could you reproduce your whole code on some online editor which I could work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i couldn't find a way for it to automatically redraw. I ended up wrapping the chart in an *ngIf that it's set to true once the chartOptions and the series are properly built.

That makes it create the chart when no more data will be added.
Hiding that under a loading spinner does the trick